# How to comment out a HTML line with Php inside?

Tags: php, html

I know the answer is easy but I can't find it anywhere..
How to disable this line?
I tried this but id doesn' work

```
// 
<!-- -->
/* */

<a class="switch" data-mode="<?php echo Session::cookieExists("myTheme", "dark") ? "dark" : "light";?>">
```

Comment: Wrap it in `<?php /* ... */ ?>`

Comment: @apokryfos But I want to disable all the line not only php.. You mean to write <!-- <a class... and after <?php /* ?

Comment: No `<?php` opens a PHP code block. Everything within that block between `/* */` is a PHP comment so will not be executed or appear in the resulting HTML

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add two comments: `<!-- -->` for HTML arround the `<p>` tag and `/* */` for PHP inside `<?php ?>`

```html
<!--
<a class="switch" data-mode="<?php /* echo Session::cookieExists('myTheme', 'dark') ? 'dark' : 'light'; */ ?>">
-->
```

Comment: Thanks @MetropolisCZ ... For some reason if I add a slash beetween </?php,  that shlash disable all the line.. i.e <!-- <a class="switch" data-mode="</?php echo Session::cookieExists("myTheme", "dark") ? "dark" : "light";?>"> -->

Comment: @programmer123 that's because it means it's not a PHP block anymore so it just treats that section as text within the html instead of executing it as PHP code

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
// <-- this is a comment in PHP, java and javascript (prob others) - NOT HTML
/* this is also a type of comment in PHP, java, javascript and css (and prob others) */
?>

<!-- This is an html comment 
   The PHP code inside it will still run, but the result will be commented out. --> 
<!-- <a class="switch" data-mode="<?php echo Session::cookieExists("myTheme", "dark") ? "dark" : "light";?>"> -->


<!-- This is the element with the PHP code inside commented out -->
<a class="switch" data-mode="<?php /* echo Session::cookieExists("myTheme", "dark") ? "dark" : "light"; */ ?>">
```

Comment: that doesn't work. You haven't add /* */ inside php, so php is still enable

Comment: @programmer123 - thx. I added that for a more complete commenting answer

Comment: @programmer123 - did this help solve your question? If so, please accept as answer. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can comment php code inside html as below:

`<a class="switch" data-mode="<?php /* echo Session::cookieExists("myTheme", "dark") ? "dark" : "light"; */ ?>">`